# Accessing variable outside of a closure in Groovy

Tags: groovy, scope, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way, i can access a variable outside the closure. The closure here is a `stage` in the `Jenkinsfile`. So, the snippet looks like this:

```
node('pool'){
 try{
     stage('init'){
   def list = []
  //some code to create the list
    }
     stage('deploy'){
   //use the list create in the above stage/closure
     } 

    }

  catch(err){
   //some mail step
   }

  }
```

With this code, i cannot access the `list` which was created in the first `stage/closure`.

How can i set to get this newly created `list` accessible to the next stage/closure?

Comment: Create it outside the closure?

Comment: @tim_yates i can do that, but i want to keep everything bundled inside stages w.r.t. the jenkinsfile. And if i done use a closure of the stage in jenkinsfile, it throws the warning, to use closure for 'stage'

Comment: Yeah, but if you put the list in the closure, you can't access it from outside the closer...  So your choices are limited ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tim_yates.. with your suggestion. This works. It was easy at the end :)

```
node('pool') {
  try {
    def list = [] //define the list outside of the closure

    stage('init') {
      //some code to create/push elements in the list
    }
    stage('deploy') {
      //use the list create in the above stage/closure
    }

  } catch (err) {
    //some mail step
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but worths mentioning that when you define a type or `def` (for dynamic resolution) you're creating a **local scope** variable that will be available only inside the closure.

If you omit the declaration the variable will be available to the whole script:

```
node('pool'){
    try {
        stage('Define') {
            list = 2
            println "The value of list is $list"
        }
        stage('Print') {
            list += 1
            echo "The value of list is $list"
        }
        1/0 // making an exception to check the value of list
    }
    catch(err){
        echo "Final value of list is $list"
    }
}
```

Returns :

```
The value of list is 2
The value of list is 3
Final value of list is 3
```